# how to fix " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: " error?

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

[#1 here's the ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G96qr.png)
[#2 project directory,layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJdTb.png)

**I tried to build the first simple HelloWorld project on Android Studio in Windows 10**

```
package com.bitch.myapp2;

    public class JavaBasics {
         public static void main(String args[]){
         System.out.println("hello bitch!!");
    }
}
```

**when i run it, i got an error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bitch.myapp2.JavaBasics
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:107)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

**whats wrong i cant figure it out?please help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

who uses a domain name like that lol XD

but anyway, it might be an issue that your project directory is somehow messed up.
if you don't mind can you post a screenshot of project directory with class folders and layout folder expanded.

Comment: i've added a SS, my project directory:  C:\Users\gagan\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2  and  <br/>SDK directory:C:\Users\gagan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: i dont know if it has something to do with Junit, can you please help.!

Comment: no. what I meant was, is your class placed in a proper directory? That is when you see from your project, it should be under `app -> java -> package name -> your class ` and also make sure that you have your activity listed in the android manifest file just like James mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class activity to manifest file.